# python - Extracting associated icon from a file

Tags: python, windows, icons

I need to extract icons from windows files using python. If a file has a custom icon I need to extract it, otherwise I need to get the default icon associated with that type of file.

I've tried using the `ExtractIconEx` function but it only works with exe files that have a custom icon.

Is there a way to extract icons from every type of file? Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa